# Sql query to select 3rd element from data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written sql query

```
   Select * from Products WHERE Products.Category=="Fruits";
```

the returned answer is

```
  1-Banana
  2-Mango
  3-Apple
  4-Oranges
  5-Grapes
```

now i want to select fruit at index 3rd only that is Apple using sql indexes 
the problem arises every where how should i select the element at 3rd place using its index in sql query?

Comment: Syntax error. Which dbms product are you using? Both MySQL and SQL Server???

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012 but i want only 3rd number limit shall give me 2 values

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. I've edited your question to remove irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql server 2012 supports [`offset` and `fetch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), so your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Products 
WHERE Products.Category ='Fruits'
ORDER BY Products.Category -- or whatever column you need the sort on
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: May be `OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY` ?

Comment: Oops, correct. fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE for finding nth place record

```
 with cte as
   (
     select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Salary desc) as r, * 
     from Products 
     WHERE Products.Category=="Fruits" e
   )
  select * from cte where r=3
```